# Wie sagt man "admit what you've done" auf Deutsch?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase

In diesem Fall verwendet man *einräumen* oder *zugeben*?

Kann man sagen z.B.

> Räum ein, was du getan hast!

Comment: Das kann man ohne den Kontext nicht beantworten.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Einräumen* und *zugeben* sind weitgehend bedeutungsgleich. Der Unterschied liegt im 'Ort der Verwendung', oder nenne es auch gerne Register der Sprache.

*Zugeben* wirst du etwas in einer Alltagssituation.

*Einräumen* wirst du es in formalisierter Sprache, etwa in einer Presseerklärung, einer Parlamentsrede, einem Rechtsstreit, etc.

Alltagssprache:

> Trump hat endlich **zugegeben**, dass er mit russischen Geheimdienstleuten zusammengearbeitet hat, um den E-Mail-Server der Demokraten zu hacken.

Formaler Stil:

> Trump hat nun endlich **eingeräumt**, er habe mit Vertreten des russischen Geheimdiensts kooperiert, um den E-Mail-Server der Demokratischen Partei zu hacken.

*Räum ein, was du getan hast* (achte auf die Wortstellung!) könntest du zwar sagen, und man würde es verstehen. Es wäre im Alltag jedoch sehr ungewöhnlich. Dein Satz klingt eher wie aus einem Theaterstück in Versen aus dem 18. oder frühen 19. Jahrhundert, oder auch aus einem mehr oder weniger simplen Gedicht:

> Zum König sprach der Untertan:
>   "Räum endlich ein, was du getan!"
>
> Drauf jener: "Lass mich doch in Ruh,
>   Ich bin ein Lump, ich geb's ja zu."

Im Alltag des 21. Jahrhunderts würdest du sagen

> Gib zu, was du getan hast!
>
> Gib schon zu, du warst es!
>
> Hast du das gemacht? Gib's zu!

PS

An Jankas Antwort auf dieser Seite, dass *zugeben* sich auf schlimmere Dinge, *einräumen* sich auf weniger schlimme beziehen kann, ist auch was dran. Allerdings wird es in der Praxis immer so sein, dass ein Politiker, der einen großen Mist baut, es - jedenfalls in seinen eigenen Verlautbarungen - niemals *zugeben* wird, allenfalls *einräumen*.

> Die USA räumten ein, es sei kriegsrechtlich problematisch gewesen, Hiroshima und Nagasaki mit Atombomben zu zerstören.

Hätten sie's mal ruhig zugegeben.

> Guttenberg räumte ein, in seiner Doktorarbeit mit wörtlichen Zitaten zu sorglos umgegangen zu sein.

Er hätte auch einfach zugeben können, dass er abgeschrieben hat.

Comment: "einräumen" heißt eher "na gut", zugeben "ja".

Comment: Ja, na gut. Ich muss einräumen, das muss ich zugeben.

Comment: Danke für die Zeit, die du für diese Antwort verbringt hast!

Answer (score 3):

Das kommt auf den Kontext an. Generell bedeutet *einräumen* ein eher kleines Zugeständnis, während *zugeben* ein allumfassendes Geständnis ist.

> Gib's zu! Du warst es!
>
> Nach kurzem Verhör gab er alles zu.
>
> <s>Nach kurzem Verhör räumte er alles ein.</s> ***(zu zwiespältig)***

Außerdem kann der Unterschied im Grad der Einsicht bestehen:

> Er **räumte ein**, dass es **(vielleicht)** ein Fehler war. *(Es war aus seiner Sicht nur ein kleiner Fehler.)*
>
> Er **gab zu**, dass es ein Fehler war. *(Er hat eingesehen, dass es ein ziemlich schlimmer Fehler war.)*

Answer (score 2):

Wird ein Vorwurf im Ganzen abgelehnt, ein Teilaspekt aber eingestanden, verwendet man eher *»einräumen«* als *»zugeben«*.

> Er wies die Kritik von sich, räumte aber ein, dass es einen noch
>   besseren Weg gegeben hätte.